# Is there such a thing as a dedicated mobile phone for mobile application security testing?

Tags: mobile

There are pentest OS distributions, like Kali Linux, and there's also Hak5 and their physical pentest gadgets.

I was wondering if there is such a phone for mobile pentesting. Nowadays, with Certificate Pinning and all-new Android security features, it becomes hard to perform pentest engagements on mobile phones. This is good for protecting against hackers but hard for ethical hacking when whitebox testing is not an option. Also, Genymotion is not always really practical and is sometimes limited...

Any idea if there is a phone dedicated or appropriate for that purpose?

Comment: Most testers simply configure their own devices as they need.

Comment: @schroeder I understand but that's not really helpful. thx anyway. What I meant is you know like gamers choose dedicated specific graphic cards, I thought it'd be possible for mobile pentesting

Comment: But if you get custom hardware and OS, are you testing the app or the bespoke environment?

Comment: @schroeder Have you ever tried to perform MITM on android latest version and also added to that the app using certificate pining ? If yes you'd know Frida is not always easy to manipulate. You'd also know rooting new devices is not a piece of cake. Therefore, the question is simply to know if there is a testing environment that could help.  I'd suggest you don't comment much if you're not used to that kind of testing because you would not understand my point and therefore be helpful. No disrespect though ;-)

Comment: That's why the testers I work with use old hardware and old OS, to give them the control and to bypass the new Android security features. I'm not suggesting that this is the final answer or even useful to you, hence my use of the comment field. I'm trying to offer my experience and to see if you need to add more requirements to your question and to make sure that you have thought through all the factors.

Comment: https://security.apple.com/research-device/

Answer (score 0):

> Does a phone built for this purpose exist?

Not that I'm aware of. There are some phones that are very easy to root, though, and others that are easy to completely replace the firmware on and have well-tested "custom ROMs" that may be more pentester-friendly.

It would be relatively easy to create a modified base Android image that allows the user to bypass certificate validation (including pinning) checks through the standard runtime (apps that do their own TLS verification, perhaps through a bundled OpenSSL or similar, would be harder to generically bypass). I'm not aware of one but it's the sort of thing people do with custom ROMs. You'd need to add the drivers, etc. for each device to the base image, but at least for some devices that's a solved problem.

Alternatively, you could try creating a modified version of the system library [javax.net.ssl.TrustManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager) - or whatever library handles [network security configurations](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) - which could be installed into a rooted but otherwise stock system to disable cert pinning / switch to pinning the tester's own certs.

I'm not aware of a library that does this currently existing, much less an Android image that incorporates such functionality. It would require some reverse engineering, though Android RE is pretty easy. If somebody has already done this (or could easily) and has released it publicly (or would be willing to), it would probably be on a phone-hacking forum/community such as xda-developers.

Comment: Well that was helpfull. Thank you vm. Would you kindly give examples of phone as you said "There are some phones that are very easy to root" and "others that are easy to completely replace the firmware on and have well-tested "custom ROMs"". One example of each category if you will please. Thank you again CBHacking

Comment: @schroeder kindly see an example of an answer I was hoping to get. CBHacking cleared doubts I had and offered a nice contribution. Kindly provide an answer like that to add on his answer if you will to help me and maybe others that may have the same interrogations. Best regards

Comment: Recommending specific products is explicitly out of scope for this site - such recommendations are obsolete too fast, and answers are supposed to be more timeless than that - but I can suggest some search strings: "best android phone for rooting" for example, which reveals that most phones are easily rooted today (that wasn't the case 7-10 years ago when I was actively hacking phones) though there's still some variation. Or "best android phone for custom ROM", which gets mostly the same sorts of results, or start with "best android custom ROM" and then "best phone for `<that ROM>`".